# Rows in columns

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have this table:

```
Id Kind
1  MODEL
1  MOTOR
2  MODEL
2  MOTOR
3  MOTOR
4  MODEL
```

And I want to insert into anothe table:

```
IdModel IdMotor
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
2       3
4       1
4       2
4       3
```

I know how to do it with cursors, but it's indeed very slow. I've tried with union but it looks like today is not my best day!

I also know this can be done in SQL 2005 with pivot, but I have to do it with SQL Server 2000.

Any Transact-SQL guru out there with a good and quick query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The table I want to create doesn't exist, so initially there is only 1 table. Yes, I want to create all possible combinations od IdModel and IdMotor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this will work:

```
INSERT Table2
SELECT model.id, motor.id
FROM
    Table model,
    Table motor
WHERE
    model.Kind = 'MODEL'
    and motor.Kind = 'MOTOR'
```

Comment: Thank you! As I say before: I'm a little down today 8-[

Comment: Wow.  +1 for partial psychic skills.  This answer assumes a different model than the question but is apparently right.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable
SELECT  [IdModel]
        , [IdMotor]
FROM    (        
          SELECT  [IdModel] = ID
          FROM    ATable
          WHERE   Kind = 'MODEL'
        ) md
        CROSS APPLY
        (
          SELECT  [IdMotor] = ID
          FROM    ATable
          WHERE   Kind = 'MOTOR'
        ) mt
```