# Manipulation on table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have table `MailSummary`:

Columns:

```
Send(Int), Reply(Int), SRT(Nvarchar(10)), NAME(Nvarchar(10))

|Send| Reply| SRT| Name|
------------------------
| 100|     8|  10|    B|
|  30|     2|  20|    R|
|   5|     0|  30|    S|
-----------------------
```

I want to transform the table and get a new result set like:

```
Sum(Send), Sum(Reply)
```

and show the name in columns and the value of SRT under the new columns

```
|Send| Reply| B | R | S |
-------------------------
| 135|    10| 10| 20| 30|
```

How can I do it in a SQL query?

Comment: does this only need to work for three values (B, R, S) or dynamically?

Comment: Hi,It does not matter. both of them will be very helpful, 10x.

Comment: There are already many answers on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134063/select-rows-as-column-in-select
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578500/how-to-select-columns-as-rows

Comment: Thanks about your examples, but how can I sum the two columns (Send,Reply) and also select the rows into columns. I need an example if you can demonstrate on my question it will be very helpful.

Comment: Why is `SRT` an `Nvarchar(10)` when it apaprently stores integers?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for your scenario:

```
SELECT SUM(Send) as Send,
       SUM(Reply) as Reply,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Name = 'B' THEN SRT END) AS B,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Name = 'R' THEN SRT END) AS R,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Name = 'S' THEN SRT END) AS S
FROM   TEST
```

Though for a more dynamic query, you will want [a dynamic cross tab query](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/).

Example on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0ddc/12

Comment: This does four queries against `TEST`. Only one is needed.

Comment: thanks. I will check the cross tab query. you were very helpful. have a nice weekend.