# changing rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to flip the rows and columns by MODEL from the below tABLE

```
------------------------
MODEL   YEAR    PRICE
------------------------
AUDI    2012    45 LAKHS
BENZ    2013    40 LAKHS
BMW     2011    38 LAKHS
```

I want a sql query to flip the table (rows as coloumns)

```
---------------------------------------
Model      AUDI      BENZ     BMW 
----------------------------------
Year       2012      2013     2011
Price      45Lakhs   40Lakhs  38Lakhs
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031846/manipulate-results-to-display-rows-as-columns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699997/sql-server-transpose-rows-into-columns

Comment: Please search "Pivot in sql server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this it perfectly works

```
CREATE TABLE SOMEDATA(
                        MODEL varchar(10), 
                        YEAR  int, 
                        PRICE int
                        )

INSERT INTO SOMEDATA VALUES('AUDI'  ,   2012  ,  45)
INSERT INTO SOMEDATA VALUES('BENZ'  ,   2013  ,  40)
INSERT INTO SOMEDATA VALUES('BMW'  ,   2011  ,  38)


select * from SOMEDATA 

SELECT 'Year' as Model, AUDI, BENZ,BMW
FROM (
SELECT MODEL, YEAR
FROM SOMEDATA) up
PIVOT (avg(YEAR) FOR MODEL IN (AUDI, BENZ,BMW )) AS pvt

UNION  ALL 

SELECT 'Price' as Model, AUDI, BENZ,BMW
FROM (
SELECT MODEL,Price
FROM SOMEDATA) up
PIVOT (avg(Price) FOR MODEL IN (AUDI, BENZ,BMW )) AS pvt

drop table SOMEDATA
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of references about it:

[how to select columns as rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578500/how-to-select-columns-as-rows)

[Rows in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370629/rows-in-columns)

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/